# writing a C/C++ daemon (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, boost, ubuntu

I want to write a generic (C/C++) library that I will use to develop daemons in the Linux environment. Rather than reinventing the wheel, I thought I'd come in here to find out if there are any well known libraries in use.

The library could be either C or C++ - although I would prefer C++ (maybe something that was part of, or based on the excellent [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/) library?).

As an aside, in terms of library selection criteria, since daemons are pretty 'mission critical' components, it would be much better if the library that you propose is actively maintained by a group of developers (e.g. the BOOST library [again]), has an active community (or at least a mailing list to resort to when faced with tricky situations), rather than a lone individual somewhere out there ...

I saw this [document](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html), which is a good starting point, but it is slightly dated, so I'm wondering if there is anything better and more well known/used out there ... ?

BTW, I will be developing on Ubuntu (10.0.4)

Comment: [start-stop-daemon](http://linuxreviews.org/man/start-stop-daemon/) may help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative solution is to use a process monitor such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), which manages multiple services, restarts them when they crash, provides a minimalistic web page to view and control the status of processes, can manage groups of services, supports a general-purpose status-change event forwarding mechanism and other goodies. Such tools give you far more value than a daemon library would.

Comment: +1: Oh snap!, why didn't I think of that?!. This could save me a lot of time. I'll look into it and see if it fufils my requirements.

Comment: Document, you're linking to is up to date, cause nothing changed since  that times in daemon behavior. And, as Marcelo said, supervisord is right for that sorts of things -- it can daemonize even simple /bin/cat program (see docs for supervisord).

Comment: @Matt: AFAIK, upstart doesn't monitor long-running processes or restart crashes services. I don't know upstart very well, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

has

```
int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose);
```

Which forks, detatches from the controlling terminal, reopens all of {stdin, stdout, stderr} to /dev/null, and changes the working directory to the root directory.  (based on flags, of course)

Answer (score 1):

If your daemon uses tcp/ip sockets, you can use the inet daemon (or xinetd). Your process is started on demand as a new incoming connection comes in. There may be scalability issues in the event of large scale deployment, however.